# Append row when clicking corresponding add button

Tags: javascript, html

Here almost we have completed the functionality.When we clicking on add button of each row will create a new table in a row.Here the problem is while clicking the first main add button
its appending to next row of the second main row.

It should come in order while clicking the corresponding row means the sub table row should come.

[See it in action here](http://jsfiddle.net/sunilcse24/TuSzA/5/)

### Screenshot

http://img28.imageshack.us/img28/5499/immwa.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:
in addEvent function

```
 e.innerHTML = '<button onClick="addSubRow('+row+',this);">Add</button>';
```

in addSubRow function:

```
$(html).insertAfter($(self).parent().parent())
```

example:
[in action](http://jsfiddle.net/PqYMF/)